# Which type of user should you create?

Tags: sql-server

I plan to pass exam "Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012".

I want the proper logical answer and understand it more.

Question is:

> You use a contained database named ContosoDb withina domain. You need
>   to create a user who can log on to the ContosoDb database. You also
>   need to ensure that you can port the database to different database
>   servers within the domain without additional user account
>   configurations. Which type of user should you create?

Possible answers:

```
 A. User mapped to a certificate
 B. SQL user without login
 C. Domain user
 D. SQL user with login
```

source: [Which type of user should you create?](http://www.aiotestking.com/microsoft/which-type-of-user-should-you-create-2/)

Comment: What hast thou tried?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to actually try, that's why I am asking for explanation. I investigated but still don't know clear difference. I am still in process of learning and I am asking for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is C obviously. The only type of users that isn't linked to the actual SQL Server instance, but to something in the domain, is the account based on the domain user (so B and D are invalid, since they are bound to the instance).

Certificates don't have to do anything with it, so that would make A invalid too.

Answer (score 1):

It is a contained database so the correct answer is:
B. SQL user without login

With all the other options you would need to configure the login on another server, even the domain user (you would have to grant login to the instance for the domain user), and the question specifically states:
"without additional user account configurations"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable

Apologies for bringing up an old thread.